# UITextView Vertical Alignment in iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, sdk, uitextview, ios7.1

I used this codes in my app to align my `textView` vertically center and it was working until `iOS 7.1`.

I guess `contentSize` property is changed in `iOS 7.1`
how can you help me with that?

```
    [textView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:    (NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
UITextView * tv = object;
CGFloat topCorrect = (tv.bounds.size.height - tv.contentSize.height * tv.zoomScale) / 2.0;
topCorrect = (topCorrect < 0 ? 0 : topCorrect);
tv.contentOffset = (CGPoint) {.x = tv.contentOffset.x, .y = - topCorrect};
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and what worked for me was using 
`[tv sizeThatFits:tv.bounds.size].height` instead of  `tv.contentSize.height`

Comment: tnx, it works but can't be observed like contentSize

Comment: Yes, that true, but I guess that for most purposes you can just observe Text and Font